# Search all programs within a package for a MODIFY statement

Tags: abap

I want to search all programs - within a package - that use the statement:

modify itab_xyz from wa_itab_xyz

> Preferably, the string should be searched with wild cards like itab*
> for a range of  itab_(values) like  itab_abc,  itab_def,  itab_ghi
> etc..

How do i do this in SAP ABAP?

Below is a screenshot of all programs within a package one can search from.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility would be to use program RS_ABAP_SOURCE_SCAN.
You can restrict the selection by package and you can also enter a specific string to search for in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I use the transaction code_scanner (program is afx_code_scanner).

The biggest problem with this program and the RS_ABAP_SOURCE_SCAN provided above is that they won’t find everything.  IMO the most important missing component to them is implicit enhancements.  They can be very impactful to system functions, and if you are searching for an error message or hard coded value skipping them could mean not finding something critical.

At the time I looked (about 7 years ago), I was unable to find a delivered tool that would actually scan all the code in the system.  I ended up enhancing the code_scanner to look for enhancements, WDA components, BSP code, and forms code.

I don’t know if the open source component above includes those.  At first glance it doesn’t seem to, but I don’t have time to really dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool from the Galileo-Open Source library. This program searches ABAP Source, OTR-Texts, Message and Textpools for static Text, wildcard patterns or regex patterns.

ABAP-Coding:
https://github.com/galileo-group/galileo-abap-lib/blob/master/%23gal%23devtools_find_text.prog.abap

Textpool:
https://github.com/galileo-group/galileo-abap-lib/blob/master/%23gal%23devtools_find_text.prog.xml

It refers to some additional classes from the library, so you either need to copy these as well or just use ABAPgit to get the whole library. You can also contact me, so I can send you a transport containing the library.

Additional information (October 1, 2020):

I created a version of the report that you can copy/paste to the ABAP editor. It is too long to include it in the response, but you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/8qZYSwVC).
Do not forget to copy the text elements / selection texts.

```
Required Text Elements:
-----------------------
B00 Scope
B01 Search pattern
H01 Type
H02 Name
H03 Key
H04 Match

Required Selection Texts:
-------------------------
P_CASE    Case-sensitive
P_DEVC    Package
P_LANGU   Language
P_MESS    Messages
P_OTR     OTR Texts
P_PATT    Pattern
P_REGEX   Regular expression
P_SOURCE  ABAP sources
P_TPOOL   Textpools
P_WILDC   Wildcard pattern
```

Comment: Wiil it be sufficient if I copy/paste and run the report: /gal/devtools_find_text in ABAP easy access?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some dependencies to other classes in the library. You also need to copy the classes /gal/abap_repository and /gal/regex and replace the type /gal/stringtable with type STRING_TABLE.

Comment: I added a link to a version that you can copy/paste to my response.