# Scan ABAP report for a string unfolding the method calls up to level N?

Tags: nested, abap, code-analysis

Sometimes I need to search for a string pattern, it's easy in to do in the single program unit, but sometimes I need to search also further method calls inside this unit. Or even maybe search inside the other methods inside these method calls, i.e. on the 2nd depth level of call stack.

I always start searching a report like this:

```
READ REPORT lr_dummy_repo INTO lv_src.
FIND FIRST OCCURRENCE OF 'select abc' IN TABLE lv_src IGNORING CASE.
```

In this report I have method calls I wanna search too.

Is there an efficient way I can search the string in automated way, at least for 2 levels of method nesting?

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042868/search-all-programs-within-a-package-for-a-modify-statement/64043305#64043305

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai Not really. As I need something that also scans the code inside the method calls present in a code.

Comment: We have no idea what you currently do to find a string, so it's difficult to tell you how to restrict your code to 2 levels. Please add an example too, I'm not sure to understand when a given occurrence is "valid", and when it is "invalid".

Comment: I believe the OP needs smth like dynamic code analyzer with search facilities, smth like [OpenGrok](https://oracle.github.io/opengrok/), [LXR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXR_Cross_Referencer) etc. The thing that doesn't exist for ABAP

Comment: @SandraRossi I have added a little more detail to what I am currently doing

Comment: What is your logic to determine what is level 1 and what is level 2?

Comment: @SandraRossi Level 1 is the report I am starting my search from and level 2 will be the method call inside the report. At the moment, there is no logic that keeps track of this.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have no ability to find the specified string in the program including all the callstack upwards. The reasons are:

- ABAP has a lot of abilities to call program elements dynamically: for example, `CALL METHOD (name)` and `PERFORM (sname) IN PROGRAM (pname)` allows dynamic method name and dynamic subroutine name and program name, `CALL FUNCTION '<funcname>'` and `CALL TRANSACTION ta` supposes dynamic function name and transaction name by default. So you cannot get the code unit until runtime.
- ABAP supports object-oriented approach, where individual instance of object supposed to implement only some interface, without need to know exact code that will be called.
- ABAP allows you to build programs dynamically and run them with `GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL`, where you also cannot know the code before the direct run of program.

So it is better to describe the exact task you need to accomplish, maybe there is more simple way to do this.

Generally, you could use different FM's to read source code (for example `SEO_METHOD_GET_SOURCE`), read its output line by line, find places that calls something and recursively do the same.